# linq in silverlight with C#

Tags: c#, linq, silverlight, caching, database-performance

I cache some tables 
and use where and Any with LINQ

```
Result = Result.Where(r => smsRoleFunctional.Any((b => b == r.Field<Guid?>("Functional_PCode")))).ToList();
```

performance is ok but when I add or condition

```
Result = Result.Where(r => smsRoleFunctional.Any((b => b == r.Field<Guid?>("Functional_PCode") || r.Field<Guid?>("Functional_PCode") == null))).ToList();
```

performance is not ok

how to write this query with or condition that perfomance become better

Comment: Is this a SQL Server database?  Have you tried investigating the resulting query's performance with SQL Profiler?

Comment: You need to tell us what kind of linq this is (linq2sql, linq2entity), what database you are using, etc. Generally, LINQPad is good to translate linq2entity to SQL, and from there you can use SSMS to get the execution plan for the query.